# Cardview animation in anddroid

Tags: android-cardview

I have a list of cards. When someone taps on that card, it should expand from that position and then open a fragment which contains the description of that card. It is exactly similar to what happens in the BuzzFeed app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shared Element Activity Transition** is what you are looking for I think. This [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition) might help you.